# Setting an element value in a php soap proxy class

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm having trouble setting an element-value in my soap request with php5.
I'm using php's native SoapClient.

I've mapped the request-object from a webservice to a proxy-class with classmaps.
The request-object should be tranfered to the webservice like this:

```
<soapElement attributename="attribValue">elemValue</soapElement>
```

My proxy-class look like this:

```
class someRequest {

    public $attributename;
    public $value; //wild guess

}
```

I initialize the class and set the variables like this:

```
$someReq = new someRequest();
$someReq->attributename = 'attribValue';
$someReq->value = 'elemValue';
```

When I call the webservice with my request:

```
$client->someOperation($someReq);
```

my request will look like this:

```
<soapElement attributename="attribValue"/>
```

As you can see the soapElement value is empty.
How can I set the value of soapElement using my proxy-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is wondering about this, I've found the answer now:

The variable name representing the element-value need to be named $_.

The following code will work:

```
class someRequest {

    public $attributename;
    public $_; 

}
```

and

```
$someReq = new someRequest();
$someReq->attributename = 'attribValue';
$someReq->_ = 'elemValue';
```

The request will then look like this:

```
<soapElement attributename="attribValue">elemValue</soapElement>
```